# Is it possible to cause the browser to cache a user action?

Tags: javascript

I've added a button on a website so the user can leave it in "night mode". But if he goes to a new story, the site will have night mode turned off.

Is it possible to have the browser cache this information, so that once it leaves the mode in night mode, the other news it accesses are already with this class?

```
var menu = document.querySelector('body.single-news');
var button = document.querySelector('button#skin-btn');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var open = menu.classList.contains('light-skin');
    menu.classList.toggle('light-skin');
});
```

Removing the "light-skin" class activates the night mode.

Comment: The search term you are looking for is `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a few examples on how to do so using localStorage and sessionStorage [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

But generally, you can create a custom variable stored by the browser.

The localStorage object has no expiration date whereas the sessionStorage object is deleted when the browser tab in question is closed.

Usage:

```
localStorage.setItem("myVariableName", "myVariableValue");
```

or

```
localStorage.myVariableName = "myVariableValue";
```

and retrieved via

```
var x = localStorage.getItem("myVariableName");
```

or

```
var x = localStorage.myVariableName;
```

The syntax for sessionStorage is identical.